# React Hook Forms errors testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I want to test with Jest the errors from react hook forms.

This is my input:

```js
<FormControl
        id="first-name"
        isInvalid={errors.name}
        w={['100%', '100%', '100%']}
      >
        <Input
          name="name"
          placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'form.business.name',
            defaultMessage: 'Business name',
          })}
          {...register('name', { required: true })}
        />
        {errors.name && (
          <FormErrorMessage>{errors.name.message}</FormErrorMessage>
        )}
</FormControl>
```

And this is what i've tried to do, its not working, but you can get an idea of what i'm trying to do.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, WrapperForm } from '@utils/test-utils'
import { InputName } from '@components/forms/signup/inputs'

describe('InputName Unit Test', () => {
    it('should display correct error message', () => {
      const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(
        <WrapperForm>
          <InputName />
        </WrapperForm>
      )

      fireEvent.click(getByPlaceholderText('Business name'))
      fireEvent.focusOut(getByPlaceholderText('Business name'))

      getByPlaceholderText('Businesss name')

      expect(findByText('name is required').innerHTML).toEqual('name is required')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the error message?

Apart from that, you might want to use the [screen](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screen) export from the testing library for querying instead.

Also, the `findBy...` queries are [async](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries) by default so you should `await` them whenever you use them.

Comment: the error message is just a div with the text 'name is required'

Comment: I meant the test failing message